# How do I get the *real* url of a link from Google search list?

Tags: android, browser, google-search

I'm developing a web browser in android environment, when i perform a search in google, and then i get google search results list. the url of these results is something like that :

http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2F&ei=yTOhT7yIGcmu6AG29aSfCQ&usg=AFQjCNH21KLjC0CBkjon2DwD_CZ0HAp

this google url send me to the real page : http://www.test.com

Google uses that type of URL to track which links people click on. but, for me i need the real url, so is there a way to get the real url (http://www.test.com) from google redirect url (http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fww ... )

I don't want substring the url from the long string and make some replacements to get the real page url because, it's not a reliable way to do it, since i will depend on google url structure, maybe they will change their parameters names in the future, so my method won't work in this case ...

So, i would like to know if there is a way to know What url has a redirect link sends me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully, Google returns something like http://www.google.ca/url?xxx=...&yyy=...&url=real_url&zzz=...  That is, the real URL is in the `url` GET parameter of the url returned by Google.  All you need to do is parse the URL returned by google - the real URL will be in the `url` GET parameter of the response.  Don't forget to do the `url_decode` on it.

Another way of doing it is to take the full URL that google returns and do HTTP GET on it.  You should receive a 301 or 302 redirect.  From that response, read the value of `location` header - this will be your real URL.

Comment: yes you'r right , BUT, as i said in my post, i don't want to use this solution, because i have to depend on google, i mean, if google for example decide to change their parameter name : ..&url=real_url&... to this name : ..&gurl=real_url&... my method will not work in this case, because what I'm supposed to do is extract the sub string from the this word "&url"

Comment: @AlaouiGhita it's not really a substring extraction, but I still hear you.  However there may not much you really can do about it.  If this is what google returns...  To start with, how are you sending the query to google?

Comment: for your question, I'm not sending a query to google, i have a web browser, i enter in my address bar google.com,when i get the site, i search for "something",i get google page result, when i click on one of the result links, i go to the result page, but the url of this page is the "long google url", so that what my browser display in the address bar, but i want it display me only the real url in the address bar

Comment: @AlaouiGhita I'm updating my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: i like this solution. i will explore it

Comment: yes it works thank you for your help, and this is the code :   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpParams params = client.getParams();
     HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);
     HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url);
     HttpResponse resp = null;
 resp = client.execute(method);
     String location = resp.getLastHeader("Location").getValue();
 Log.i("url", location);

Comment: Also remember that google could still change this and simply use the "real" url of the website, in which case you'll be using `test.com` thinking it's google and waiting for a redirect when it'll be a real web page.

A more robust way would be to check if the domain of the link  contains google or not, if not, it's probably the "real" URL. If the domain contains google.*, try to get the URL from the GET parameter and unescape the value, then check if it's a valid URL. If all fails, then by all means call the link and check the `location` header.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that google could change the links it provides, simply using the "real" url of the website in the search results.

A robust way covering the foreseeable future would be:

1. check if the **domain** of the link contains google or not, if not, it's probably the "real" URL
2. if the domain contains *google.**, try to get the URL from the GET parameter and unescape the value, then check if it's a valid URL.
3. if all fails, then by all means call the link and check the `location` header.

If you're able to log when anything fails, you can check what went wrong and why.